# Application_End event in Asp.net is raised more than once

Tags: asp.net

I have two same applications: sharing same physical project and same application pool but they are hosted via two different ports, 80 and 81. I use log4Net to log from the Application_Start and _End handlers. I distinguish this two applications by also logging HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath because one of them is set up as sub application. What I have found is that occasionally, Application_End event is called more than once for one application when application pool is recycled (as i can see the virtual path). Is that normal? Is that because of Log4Net? Hope someone could give me the answer.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) states that Application_End is "called once per lifetime of the application before the application is unloaded"; so it sounds abnormal.  Is there an extra `Application_Start` in between the two End calls?

Comment: @harpo surely not. I have seen four consecutive log entry of Application_End events. sounds weird!

Comment: Is this happening in the parent application or the child application, or both?

Comment: @ This is happening in the parent/standalone application. I haven't checked it in the sub application. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you reproduce it?  If so, try removing the child application and see if it still happens.

Comment: @harpo I can reproduce it.But at the moment, I cannot remove child application for some reasons. I will try it later. If you have another suggestion or any knowledge or reference re this problem, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest that you reporduce the problem for another empty project, and then isolate chances like "Is it because Log4net?". What is your IIS version??